# Präposition ab + Datumsangabe

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, article

Noch eine Frage zum Gebrauch des Kasus in Kombination mit Datumsangabe.

Neulich bekam ich eine Mail:

> Leider wird Ihr Dirndl erst **ab dem Montag** zugestellt.

Der Gebrauch des Artikels nach der Präposition *ab* gefolgt vom Wochentag ist mir neu. Ich dachte, der Artikel tritt auf, wenn ein konkretes Datum angegeben wird (oder wenn ein adjektivisches Attribut steht, wie z.B. *ab kommendem Montag*...). Der Name der Dame aus dem Trachtenladen, von der die E-Mail stammt, klingt deutsch, daher nahm ich mal an, sie würde korrektes Deutsch schreiben. Aber irgendwie habe ich immer noch Zweifel... Ist es wirklich richtig – *ab + Artikel + Wochentag*?

PS: … und sollte es eigentlich nicht heißen: *am Montag* statt *ab dem Montag* (das Paket wird ja an einem präzisen Tag geliefert)?

Danke schön!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stilistisch ist das schon bedenklich, für wirklich falsch halte ich diese Formulierung aber nicht. Vermutlich soll damit ausgedrückt werden, dass ein bestimmter Montag gemeint ist.

Ich weiß nicht, ob das im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum gilt, oder eher nur dort wo Dirndl und Lederhosen getragen werden, aber ich kenne die Formulierung

> die Lieferung kommt an **diesem** Montag an

sehr gut, womit ausdrücklich der unmittelbar nächste Montag (und kein späterer Montag) gemeint ist. Und weil das Demonstrativpronomen *dieser* durch *dem* ersetzt werden kann, ist mit

> die Lieferung kommt an **dem** Montag an

genau dasselbe gemeint, wobei hier beim Sprechen das Pronomen *dem* ganz besonders betont wird, um es vom Artikel *dem* zu unterscheiden.

Da sich die Absenderin des Dirndls vermutlich nicht sicher war, ob es genau **am** Montag, oder vielleicht doch erst am Dienstag ankommt, wird sie - völlig korrekterweise - *an* durch *ab* ersetzt haben:

> die Lieferung kommt **ab diesem** Montag an
>   die Lieferung kommt **ab dem** Montag an

Aber weil beim Leser unklar bleibt, ob mit *dem* der Artikel oder das Demonstrativpronomen gemeint ist, ist diese Formulierung im geschriebenen Deutsch eher nicht zu empfehlen.